# Can I use a C compiler from behind WSL?

Tags: compile, windows, ccompilerdriver

I've got 13.3 on Windows 11 (22H2) and a gnu compiler suite under WSL2 (Arch). Seems it is possible to compile in Windows with VS Code (which I also have). Do I still need to install another C compiler in Windows per se to use `CompilationTarget -> C` in Mathematica?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I still need to install another C compiler in Windows

Yes. You need a compiler that targets Windows, not Linux.